# Renderizar modal con datos de un submodal REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Buen dia tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo un componente modal (le llamaremos modal 1) en el que necesito que el usuario llene información, en este modal abro otro segundo componente modal(le llamaremos modal 2) y según los datos rellenados en el modal 2 necesito que esa información se muestre en el modal 1 pero el modal 1 no se renderiza aunque su state si cambia

---

Estoy usando hooks y no utilizo clases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería necesario ver un poco de tu código para saberlo, pero probablemente el problema es que React no logra encontrar un motivo para volver a renderizar tu componente.

Te recomiendo que revises que no estés mutando ningún estado, es decir:

```javascript
// No hagas esto
tuEstado = nuevoValor;
setTuEstado(tuEstado);

// Haz esto
const nuevoEstado = [...tuEstado];
setTuEstado(nuevoEstado);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta definir un componente que sea "padre" de modal1. Dentro de este componente, define un hook de estado (`useState`) en donde guardes los valores que deseas mostrar, y pásale estos valores como props a tus modales. De esta manera React actualizará los componentes de manera automatica por ti.